# Push Notifications or Intents to Phone from BLE Device when App is turned off

Tags: android, ios, android-intent, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an BLE smart device that at any time should be able to inform the android cellphone of it's current state.

If I previously bounded the BLE device to my phone with my application but **I have the app turned off**. Can I then send an `intent` or `notification` to the phone from the BLE device to open the app or inform the user that something happened?

I also need to make the same functionality for IOS later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a background Service class which scans for BLE devices. When app comes in device proximity, you can send a notification to the user. Remember,your device bluetooth should be turned on always.

Comment: So I would start this service when starting the Android phone? (from an android boot intent) And then it would scan for the device until a user goes into the service preferences of the phone and manually kills it or the phone runs out of memory and Android kills it? I can see that there are many types of services in Android, any idea which would would be best to use?

Comment: Are you using beacons?

Comment: Yes I do use beacons

Comment: Which library are you using?